Jumper Tech EZbook S5 PCI Device needs further installation by Windows 11 and USB flash drives not recognized
I was given a Jumper Tech EZbook S5 with the Apollo Lake Intel(R) Celeron(R) CPU N3350 @ 1.10GHz and Win11 Home installed.
I found the USB ports could not recognize USB flash drives.
Device Manager reported a PCI Device missing a driver, showing a yellow exclamation point with the 'device needs further installation' message.
That PCI Device had a Hardware ID of Device+PCI\VEN_8086&DEV_5AA2&SUBSYS_72708086&REV_0B.
The Jumper Tech website has many drivers to download for audio devices, but nothing for PCI devices and no help shown for a PCI device problem.
À week after I wrote to the manufacturer in Shenzen, I received no response.
An automatic search for a driver for the PCI device showing a yellow bang in Device Manager did not help, and neither did browsing the entire drive.
Uninstalling and removing the driver followed by a reboot did not find a driver for that device.
Windows Update did not find a driver.
Ran Control Panel > System and Security > Security and Maintenance > Security and Maintenance > Automatic Maintenance  to check for issues but didn't find a solution.
sfc/scannow run as an Administrator did not find any problem.
The PC HelpSoft Driver Updater app did find a driver for the PCI device and installed it, but after a reboot, 32GB USB flash drives proven good on other PCs still were not recognized.
How may I troubleshoot further to resolve this problem?

I've a third party app that does pretty nice for things like this. Makes use of driver packs and is a bit of a big upload. https://www.snappy-driver-installer.org its very 90s looking but seems to do the trick on some of the odder stuff I've run.

Your hardware is not compatible with Windows - your generation was bundled with Windows 10 - so problems ARE to be expected. The current gen Jumper EZbook S5 is compatible and pre-installed with Windows 11.

ChanganAuto, you got any solution to revert to Win10, then, without working USB ports?

Can you confirm if the "PC HelpSoft Driver Updater app" which installed a driver for the PCI device has made the the 'device needs further installation' message go away in device manager? PCI vendor 8086  device 5AA2 is a "Celeron N3350/Pentium N4200/Atom E3900 Series Integrated Sensor Hub" according to PCIlookup, and I'm not sure if a missing driver for the Integrated Sensor Hub" would stop USB flash drives from being recognised.

Are the USB ports completely unresponsive, or is only that  USB flash drives are not recognized? E.g. does something like a USB mouse work in the ports?

Journeyman Geek https://superuser.com/users/10165/journeyman-geek - if you will create an answer I will mark it as successful as your app solved the problem once the torrent download finally completed.

Chester Gillon - The flash drives were not recognized at all until I ran Journeyman Geek's app. Now they are, problem solved.
